# ElasticSearch - Searching with hyphens

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

I want to index text that contains hyphens, for example U-12, U-17, WU-12, t-shirt... and to be able to use a "Simple Query String" query to search on them.

Data sample (simplified):

```
{"title":"U-12 Soccer",
 "comment": "the t-shirts are dirty"}
```

As there are quite a lot of questions already about hyphens, I tried the following solution already:

Use a Char filter: [ElasticSearch - Searching with hyphens in name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23637493/elasticsearch-searching-with-hyphens-in-name).

So I went for this mapping:

```
{
  "settings":{
    "analysis":{
      "char_filter":{
        "myHyphenRemoval":{
          "type":"mapping",
          "mappings":[
            "-=>"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer":{
        "default":{
          "type":"custom",
          "char_filter":  [ "myHyphenRemoval" ],
          "tokenizer":"standard",
          "filter":[
            "standard",
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings":{
    "test":{
      "properties":{
        "title":{
          "type":"string"
        },
        "comment":{
          "type":"string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Searching is done with the following query:

```
{"_source":true,
  "query":{
    "simple_query_string":{
      "query":"<Text>",
      "default_operator":"AND"
    }
  }
}
```

1. What works:

   - "U-12"
   - "U*"
   - "t*"
   - "ts*"
2. What didn't work:

   - "U-*"
   - "u-1*"
   - "t-*"
   - "t-sh*"

So it seems the char filter is not executed on search strings?

What could I do to make this work?

I am using Elastic Search 1.6.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The answer is really simple:

Quote from Igor Motov: [Configuring the standard tokenizer](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/configuring-the-standard-tokenizer/8691/5)

> By default the simple_query_string query doesn't analyze the words
>   with wildcards. As a result it searches for all tokens that start with
>   i-ma. The word i-mac doesn't match this request because during
>   analysis it's split into two tokens i and mac and neither of these
>   tokens starts with i-ma. In order to make this query find i-mac you
>   need to make it analyze wildcards:

```
{
  "_source":true,
  "query":{
    "simple_query_string":{
      "query":"u-1*",
      "analyze_wildcard":true,
      "default_operator":"AND"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The [quote from Igor Motov](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/configuring-the-standard-tokenizer/8691/5) is true, you have to add `"analyze_wildcard":true` in order to make it work with regex. But it is important to note that the hyphen actually tokenizes `"u-12"` into `"u"` and `"12"`, which are two separated words.

If preserving the original text is important, do not use `mapping` `char_filter`. Otherwise, it is kind of useful.

Imagine that you have `"m0-77"`, `"m1-77"`, and `"m2-77"`. If you search for `m*-77`, you are going to get zero hits. However, you can replace the `"-"` (hyphen) with `AND` in order to connect the two separated words, and then search for `m* AND 77`, and that is going to give you a correct hit.

You can do it from the client side.

For example, for `u-*`:

```
{
  "query":{
    "simple_query_string":{
      "query":"u AND 1*",
      "analyze_wildcard":true
    }
  }
}
```

For example, for `t-sh*`:

```
  {
      "query":{
        "simple_query_string":{
          "query":"t AND sh*",
          "analyze_wildcard":true
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is still looking for a simple workaround to this issue, replace hyphen with underscore `_` when indexing data.

For eg, O-000022334 should indexed as O_000022334.

When searching, replace underscore back to hyphen again when displaying results. This way you can search for "O-000022334" and it will find a correct match.

Comment: What about if already have underscore "_" in data, while replacing  to hypen display output will be wrong..

Comment: If source data has an underscore, you obviosuly don't need to replace it with a hyphen.

Comment: @Jesal He means, what if it has both and they should be considered distinct. For example if you have two items "O_000022334" and "O-000022334" in your data and if you search for "O-000022334" you want to find only item "O-000022334".